# Java Client-Server : "While loop" problem

Tags: java, while-loop, server, client

I'm currently working on developing a Client-Server multi-thread where the server ask a question "Guess my secretNumber" and the Client have to find it.

What's working : messages between client & server

What's not working : when the client find the secretNumber, I want to get out of the while because currently, when my client found the secretNumber, the server send him "Congratulations, you found it" but the client still receives message to send a secretNumber.

Can you help me? I'm pretty sure that my issue come from the client's while.

Below my code :

Server

```
while(true) {
        String req;
        fin = false;
        while ((req=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(nom+" a envoyé "+req);
            int nb=Integer.parseInt(req);
            System.out.println("Nombre secret " + nombreSecret);
            if (fin==false) {
                if(nb<nombreSecret) {
                    pw.println("Le nombre secret est plus grand");
                    //String petit = br.readLine();
                }
                else if(nb>nombreSecret) {
                    pw.println("Le nombre secret est plus petit");
                    //String grand = br.readLine();
                }
                else {
                    gagnant=nom;
                    pw.println("BRAVO " + nom + " !!!! Le nombre secret était " + nombreSecret + " ... Vous êtes le vainqueur");
                    fin=true;
                    //String vainqueur = br.readLine();
                }
            }
            else {
                pw.println("Le jeu est terminé ! Le gagnant est : "+nom);
                //String finish = br.readLine();
            }
            
            String rep="Size = "+req.length();
            pw.println(rep);
    }
    
}
```

Client

```
while(true) {   

    System.out.println("Votre nombre : ");
    String req=scanner.nextLine();
    pw.println(req);
    
    String message3 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(message3);
    
    String message4 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(message4);   
}
```

Comment: is it homework ?

Comment: @AntonioMiranda is that relevant?

Comment: Well.. today exist better techs to develop Server-Clients. Answering the question, you can use your 'fin' variable in the second while statement to break it. In other way , you can use " continue;" statement to break any loop.

Comment: Thanks, for the help !! It's working but when i have multiple client playing this game, when a client found the secretNumber, the game stop for every client and they don't receive the message "Le jeu est terminé" (''The game is over'')

Comment: @RyanThibault you should spawn a new server thread every time a client connects, but that's for another question (following a bit of research on your own, of course ;-) )